# SDL C mouse/keyboard output

Tags: c, keyboard, mouse, sdl

is there any ways to press keys mouse/keyboard with sdl in C?

if yes, how?

if no, do you know any ways to do that in C?

Comment: Mouse/keyboard *output*? Are you trying to send synthesized mouse/keyboard events to another program, similar to things like [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `SDL_event` structure and fill in the fields as documented in http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_KeyboardEvent and http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keysym then use `SDL_Pushevent()` to put the event into the event queue:
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent

```
 SDL_Event event;

 event.type = SDL_KEYDOWN;
 event.timestamp = lastEvent.timestamp + 1;
 event.windowID - lastEvent.windowID;
 event.state = SDL_PRESSED;

 event.keysym.scancode = SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE; // from SDL_Keysym
 event.keysym.sym = SDLK_ESCAPE;
 event.keysym.mod = 0; // from SDL_Keymod

 SDL_PushEvent(&Event) // Inject key press of the Escape Key
```

Do the same thing for any other event in the SDL_Event union including mouse events: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent

Answer (score 2):

As of SDL 2.0.3, SDL doesn't support sending input events to other applications. On Windows you can use [the `SendInput` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) to send input events to other applications.  With X11 you can use [the `xcb_send_event` function](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/xcb_send_event.3.xhtml). I'm not sure about OS X, iOS, or Android.

Comment: re: _SDL doesn't support sending input events to other applications_. 
Is this still the case for SDL 2.0.8?

Comment: @3dGrabber From searching SDL's source for both `SendInput` and `xcb_send_event`, it still doesn't support sending input events to other programs

Answer (score -1):

This program demonstrates how to read mouse and keyboard input in an SDL program. It will run for a few seconds, and display "up arrow" or "down arrow" when either of those keys are pressed, and display "mouse clicked" and coordinates when the mouse is clicked.

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Keyboard and mouse input",
                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                         500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i< 3000; i++){
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){//this is where the important stuff happens:
            if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ) {
                switch( event.key.keysym.sym ) { 
                    case SDLK_UP: 
                        puts("up arrow");
                        break;
                    case SDLK_DOWN://for full list of key names, http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlkey.html
                        puts("down arrow");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
                int x, y;

                SDL_GetMouseState(&x,&y);
                printf("%s button mouse clicked at: (%d,%d)\n",
                    (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)? "left" : "right",
                    x,y);
            }
        }
        SDL_Delay(1);
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

this is for SDL version 2

basically, you need to call **`SDL_PollEvent`**, and then check the resulting `SDL_Event struct` for information about whether it was a keyboard or mouse event, and if so where the mouse was or what button was pressed.